# Is it possible to communicate between a PHP server and two clients one is PHP and other is JavaScript on a same socket?

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, server, client

I want to connect two clients to php server. one client is javascript and the other client is php. I want to send data from php client through socket, recieve it in php server and then send it to javascrpt client through websocket. Is it possible to acheive my goal using one socket[one port and same address] in php server?

I am already done with two way communication between PHP server and JavaScript through websocket. And I also have another code in which PHP server communicate with multiple PHP clients through socket. Now I want to merge these two different tasks and achieve the goal to receive data in PHP server from PHP client and send it to JavaScript client.

Comment: No, this is not possible. Sockets are like tunnels and can only have a pair of endpoints. For what you describe you will need 2 sockets. Not sure what advantage you would gain with one socket.